# 'How to fix' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

'How to fix' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at script

```
equalsButton.addEventListener('click',button =>{KeyboardEvent
calculator.compute()
calculator.updateDisplay()
```

Comment: Make sure equalsButton is not null.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for me:

```
equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  //calculator.compute()
  //calculator.updateDisplay()
  alert('works fine');
});
```

https://jsbin.com/busehe/2/edit

I can't reach KeyboardEvent and calculator objects, since your code looks like cut out of context. You may provide the whole code with surrounded context.